# JSON - Unable to serialize JSONObject within Object using Jackson and JPA

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a MovieService and SerieService. MovieService returns a Collection of movies, and SerieService a collection of Series.

It appears that error, I don't understand the meaning. I just want to return and show the response of the search.

```
"No serializer found for class org.udg.pds.simpleapp_javaee.rest.SearchRESTService$SearchResult and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"
```

This is my code:

```
package org.udg.pds.simpleapp_javaee.rest;

@Path("/search")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchRESTService extends RESTService {

@EJB
MovieService ms;

@EJB
SeriaService ss;

@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response search(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    if (!checkLoggedIn(req)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("User not logged.");
    }

    SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
    sr.movies = ms.getAllMovies();
    sr.series = ss.getAllSeries();
    return buildResponse(sr);
}


static class SearchResult {
    Collection<Movie> movies;
    Collection<Seria> series;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty` to the fields of SearchResult or provide a getter implementation for those fields.

From the documentation:

> The default Jackson property detection rules will find:
>
> - All ''public'' fields
> - All ''public'' getters ('getXxx()' methods)

Answer (score 0):

If your fields do not have getters/setters you can use this annotation to allow Jackson to find them

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
static class SearchResult {
```

Or you can do it globally, configuring the mapper

```
ObjectMapper youMapper= new ObjectMapper();
youMapper.setVisibilityChecker(youMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```